# Entity modifiers don't modify it childs

Tags: android, andengine

I've an `Entity` "holder" with some child `Sprites` and `ButtonSprites`.
When I do something like:

```
entity.registerEntityModifier(new FadeInModifier(ALPHA_MODIFER_DURATION));
```

nothing happens, but if I register this `EntityModifier` to the child `Sprites` one by one it works. What's happening?
ps: MoveModifier works though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since an `Entity` it's a "holder" the only `EntityModifiers` who affect `Entity` childs are the ones regarding position and size, so that's why `FadeInModifier` wont "work".